# multi column uuid primary key?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to work out the least bad way to design a table. It's a PostgreSQL database but I think the problem would be similar in other systems.

The DB is multi tenanted, so will contain data from a few hundred customers identified by a uuid customer ID. Individual table rows are identified by an item ID primary key that's also a uuid. Both uuids are generated outside of the database. Queries will always be filtered by a particular customer ID. There will be many millions of rows in the table.

As it's been developed the item ID is the PK, so data for a customer is randomly spread through the table impacting performance. Customer ID is indexed.

Changing the PK to be multi column on (customer ID, item ID) would mean that customer data would be together but two uuids as a PK seems like madness. The customer ID could be mapped to an int or something else so it's narrower (customer map, item ID) but that doesn't feel much better.

Possibly the service that generates the item ID could generate a seeded uuid where those for a customer fall in the same range. Then the seeded item ID could be the PK on its own and still provide data ordering. The item IDs are discoverable though, so genuine randomness is good.

Is there a sensible structure I can use here?

Comment: Clustering on the customer ID column could work, if you can afford to cluster on a regular basis. I have a [blog entry](https://blog.chrishowie.com/2013/02/15/lock-free-clustering-of-large-postgresql-data-sets/) on how clustering can be performed live, without a lock. You could also make use of table partitioning.

Comment: @cdhowie The table could not be unavailable for the time a normal CLUSTER would take, though your blog method may work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting situation.  One possible solution is a separate database for each client.  This would typically be driven by security requirements and the separation of data.  That would ensure that one client cannot see another client's data, even if they have full access to the database.

For your situation, it sounds like you want to partition the data by client.  This separates the data for each client for each table into its own data storage (I'm so tempted to say "file").  So, data for a given client would be collocated.  Postgres queries are generally smart enough to only fetch the partitions that are needed.

Partitioning is a somewhat complex subject, so I advise you to read the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/ddl-partitioning.html).

Comment: Gordon (and @cdhowie) It looks like partitioning may be the way to go, thanks.